# Check if string is in Variant and then replace Yes/No results with 1/0 respectively

Tags: excel, vba

giving the below code, how can I check if "outArr" value is Yes or No and replace them respectively with 1 and 0?

```vb
Sub IndexMatchFirm1()
                Dim destinationWs As Worksheet
                Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
                Dim destinationLastRow As Long
                destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Dim lkpArr As Variant
                lkpArr = destinationWs.Range("A5:A" & destinationLastRow).Value
               With Worksheets("MyData")
                Dim retval As Variant
                    retval = Intersect(.Range("E:E"), .UsedRange)
                    Dim mtch As Variant
                    mtch = Intersect(.Range("B:D"), .UsedRange)
                End With
                Dim outArr As Variant
                ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(lkpArr, 1), 1 To 1)
                Dim i As Long
                For i = 1 To UBound(lkpArr, 1)
                    Dim j As Long
                    For j = 1 To UBound(retval, 1)
                        If mtch(j, 3) = "FirmA" Then
                            Dim v
                            If mtch(j, 1) = lkpArr(i, 1) Then
                                v = retval(j, 1)
                                outArr(i, 1) = IIf(v = "Yes", 1, IIf(v = "No", 0, v))
                             End If
                             'If mtch(j, 1) = lkpArr(i, 1) Then
                                'outArr(i, 1) = retval(j, 1)
                                'Exit For
                             'End If  
                        End If
                    Next j
                Next i
             destinationWs.Range("L5").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), 1).Value = outArr
End Sub
```

I tried in many ways but none of them seems to be working.  I also would like not to use the "For each cell in myrange" approach because it slows down a lot the workbook. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You've commented out the `Exit For` in the `j` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest fix:

```vb
Dim v
'...
'...
If mtch(j, 1) = lkpArr(i, 1) Then
    v = retval(j, 1)
    outArr(i, 1) = IIf(v = "Yes", 1, IIf(v="No", 0, v)
    Exit For 'Edit - I forgot to add this....
End If
'...
'...
```

Comment: Hi Tim thanks a lot. I tried to fix the code according to your suggestion but it doesn't work, No data is retrieved.

Comment: The output is completely blank?

Comment: You maybe need to restore the `Exit For` you commented out above?

Comment: Sorry I should have included the `Exit For` in my code above...